# Returning 404 for a specific URL in nginx

Tags: php, ajax, nginx

```
location ~* ajax.php {
    if ($args ~ "action=query_new") {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

I have an ajax.php file stored in test directory of a site example.com I want to return 404 error for all requests coming to ajax.php containing the args/query string action=query_new. I wrote the above code. The code works but it makes the ajax.php file unusable i.e ajax.php is not executing when the above code is in action.  My site uses this file to process some other query strings. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your `nginx` configuration you will have a location block that looks something like `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { ... }` or simply `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`. This contains the code necessary to send the php file to the upstream interpreter.

Your new location block take precedence and prevents any file matching `ajax.php` from being executed as php.

One solution is to duplicate the code necessary to send the php file to the upstream interpreter into *both* location blocks. This might be achieved by moving those directives to a separate file and using the `include` directive to load them into each block. Something like:

```
location ~* ajax.php$ {
  if ($arg_action = "query_new") { return 404; }
  include path/to/my_php_config;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
  include path/to/my_php_config;
}
```

The `include` directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include).

Comment: you mean the code that i've added in the location ~* \.php$ block of my configuration file should be moved to location ~* ajax.php$ block? wouldn't nginx report duplicate code?

Comment: @Pramod It should be duplicated - yes. `nginx` doesn't care if multiple location blocks contain identical directives.

Comment: I'll try this strategy soon and will let you know the result. Thanks